# Special unicode characters cause exceptions in MySQL JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have isolated a problem we are running into down to a simple test:

Try to run a straight up JDBC insert or update on a longtext column type with the parameter value
new String(new char[]{0xDBFF, 0xDC00});

An exception occurs stating:
"Incorrect string value: '\xF4\x8F\xB0\x80' for column"

It appears that these two characters when paired together, form a valid Chinese symbol (individually they are meaningless)

How can I deal with these messed up characters? They form a valid symbol and Character.isDefined returns true for both characters. Stripping out specifically those character codes from all strings seems like it would be begging for more problems with different combinations of Chinese characters.

Comment: If it makes a difference, the table has utf8_bin collation

Comment: A little further checking confirms that these two characters are a 'surrogate pair'

Comment: Is the JDBC connector throwing that error message itself, or is it coming from the DB? You should make sure your table is set to `CHARSET=utf8`, not just the collation, and make sure you're using multibyte strings in your Java code. The value in your error message doesn't seem to match the `new String` create statement, which makes me think there's some encoding going on somewhere. Also, I don't know much Java, but generally `0xDBFF` would not be a char, as char is 8 bits (`0xFF` or similar), and `0xDBFF` is 16 bits.

Comment: Which MySQL (server/connector) version you are using?

Comment: We are running on MySQL Server 5.1 with the mysql-connector version 5.1.18. I think that you hit the nail on the head with your answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Encoded with `UFT-8` this character will result in 4 bytes:

> 11110100  10001111  10110000  10000000

MySQL 5.0/5.1  does not support 4byte UTF8-characters, this is a known limitation. 
MySQL 5.5 does support 4byte UTF8-characters.

See [9.1.10. Unicode Support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode.html)

Comment: This explains it perfectly. We'll have to work around it by stripping off those long UTF8 characters until we can upgrade to the latest version of MySQL. Thanks for the help!